# Complex Join to the existing query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to add the below join to the existing query. I am not aware whether the logic is correct.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
  dbo.note not
  CASE
     WHEN not.main_ref_type='M'
     THEN pem.membership_id=not.main_ref_id
     WHEN not.main_ref_type=P'
     THEN per.person_id=not.main_ref_id
  END
```

Comment: For clarity - when the `main_ref_type` is `P` then join to the table aliased as `pem` and when the `main_ref_type` is `M` then join to the table aliased as `per`

Answer (score 2):

You need an `on` clause.  It should look more like this:

```
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
  dbo.note not
  on (not.main_ref_type='M' and not.main_ref_id = pem.membership_id) or
     (not.main_ref_type='P' and per.person_id=not.main_ref_id)
```

You should know that `join`s with `or` conditions often perform badly.  In many cases, it is better to do two separate joins (to the `note` table) and then use logic in the `select` (typically `coalesce()`) to get the right values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.note nt ON (nt.main_ref_type='M'
 AND pem.membership_id=nt.main_ref_id)
 OR 
 (nt.main_ref_type='P'
 AND per.person_id=nt.main_ref_id)
```

END

Answer (score 0):

```
CROSS APPLY (
  VALUES
     ('M'     , pem.membership_id),
     ('P'     , per.person_id    )
) map(ref_type, ref_id           )
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.note not ON (
  not.main_ref_type = map.ref_type AND
  not.main_ref_id   = map.ref_id
)
```